# the act of using one word to refer to another

Tags: single-word-requests

we use the word "suits" to refer to policemen.

What is the word that describes this action? I had read this word in the book "[HHhH](http://www.amazon.co.uk/HHhH-Laurent-Binet/dp/1846554799)", but for the life of me, I can't seem to recall it...

Comment: Who uses the word "suits" to refer to policemen?

Comment: ["*Suits* instead of *officials* is metonymy"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/15567/300).

Comment: @MSPune: What part of the English-speaking world do you hail from? I don't hear *suits = police* being used in the UK, where *suits* are normally *bankers, senior corporate managers* and others whose primary allegiance is to Mammon, rather than to human creativity.

Answer (score 2):

*[Metonymy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metonymy)* (“The use of a single characteristic or name of an object to identify an entire object or related object”) is one such word – as I now see RegDwighт pointed out a half hour ago.

Comment: +1, just so. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metonymy gives similar examples, *as “scepter” for “sovereignty,” or “the bottle” for “strong drink,” or “count heads (or noses)” for “count people.” *

Comment: More specifically, it is a _synecdoche_.