# "Baby blues" - metonymy or synechdoche?

Tags: slang, metonyms, synecdoche

I understand the basic difference between *metonymy* and *synecdoche* (thanks in part to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15415)) but got stumped on "baby blues" as another way of saying eyes. Am I right that it is synecdoche as the "blue" iris is a part of the eye, even though blue is an attribute of the iris rather than the iris itself?

**Edit:** An example of what I mean by "baby blues" for eyes is "She looked away, tears sparkling in her baby blues."

Comment: @medica: Good point. I'd not thought of "the baby blues" when I wrote the question. Updated to give an example.

Comment: Typos: It's *metonymy* or *synecdoche*

Comment: There is not a consensus over the exact interrelationship between metonymy and synecdoche: overlapping sets or set and subset? Also, deletions ('baby blues' for 'baby blue eyes') complicates analysis.  As others here imply, trying to analyse this one beyond the 'it's an idiom' (whether slang or not) level is probably not advantageous. Note also that 'baby browns', 'baby grays' ... are non-idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It it's a deletion (from baby blue eyes), then it's not also a synecdoche because eyes are not a part of eyes.

Comment: @MSalters '30 000 foot', short for '30 000 footsoldiers', is considered to be a synecdoche. Wikipedia lists 'strings', short for 'string instruments', as a synecdoche. Deletion may be how most synecdoches have arisen. 'England' is used for 'the England Football Team' etc.

Comment: Hello, thought you might want to know that it's spelled [**metonymy**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metonymy), it's an awful word to spell. I always get it mixed up myself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thanks. I had it right in the body but wrong in the title. Right everywhere now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that this is only an example of [*slang*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slang): words that are not considered part of the standard vocabulary of a language and that are used very informally in speech especially by a particular group of people. - MW

It is certainly *alliterative*: the repetition of the *B* sound, but other than that, I can't really think that there is another literary device at work here.

Synecdoche is use of a part to symbolize a whole, e.g. "All *hands* on deck" means every *crew member* report to the deck. Conversely, using the whole to refer to a part, if one hears that, say, *Tennessee* is in the lead in a basketball game, we know that it's not all of Tennessee, but merely a team.

Metonymy is when the word use to describe another thing is closely linked to that particular thing, but is not a part of it. For example, "give me a *hand*" means "give me some help". Hands are usually involved, but the metonymy is using hand for help.

I'm not sure it's a metaphor (though it might be). A metaphor for blue eyes might be "azure pools to drown in" (sorry, I'm not a writer).

Oh, and as to part of speech, it functins as an adjective + noun in your sentence.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that the answer to "Is this X or Y?" might actually be "No."