# What is the term to describe the use of "City Hall" in "you can't fight City Hall"?

Tags: american-english, parts-of-speech, figures-of-speech

I know there's a word to describe the use of the words "City Hall" in the common phrase "you can't fight City Hall", where "City Hall" = "the office of the mayor of the city", but I can't remember what it is. I don't think it's *anthropomorphism* but the proper term has been on the tip of my tongue all day and I just can't bring it to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours is a textbook case of *[metonymy](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/m/metonymy.htm)*, which Silva Rhetorica by BYU's Gideon Burton defines as

> Reference to something or someone by naming one of its attributes.

*City hall* is a building associated with local government, and used metaphorically to represent local government as a whole. See also *[What is the difference between metonymy and synecdoche?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15415)*

It is not *anthropomorphism* because we are not talking about the physical building itself. An anthropomorphism might be represented by something like

> Erie's City Hall squats lazily, reaching toward State Street but never quite making it.

Comment: Yup, you nailed it. I _knew_ it wasn't "anthropomorphism", but I couldn't remember "metonymy". Thanks, choster!

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is [*metonymy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy).