# What's the linguistic term for when you use an object in place of a person who uses or is associated with that object?

Tags: linguistics

For example, a common one is calling someone who helps out a hired-*hand*. Another example is gum*shoe* for a detective, or a private *eye*. Sometimes the association might be metaphorical, like *whips* in politics. Is there a general term for this phenomenon of using objects to stand in for people who use the objects?

Comment: These linguistic devices are more generally (eg 'sail' to stand for 'ship') known as metonymy and synecdoche, which you can easily look up. There are some good articles here, eg [What is the difference between metonymy and synecdoche?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/what-is-the-difference-between-metonymy-and-synecdoche).