# Does the word "synecdoche" work in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

"Person X is a synecdoche for the American people," where Person X's traits are a representation of typical American traits. If not, what would be a better word to use?

Comment: I know no other. A synedoche is a synedoche: calling the whole by a part. However, person x cannot be a "part" of the American people. The "American people" don't have a "part".  It's usually for things. So, you might use a part of the body to refer to some individual. (Sorry, not my fault if that could end up being pretty nasty). Person X is representative of the American people. Not a synecdoche of them.

Comment: Some other words could be _stand in_ or _everyman._

Comment: Do you mean someone like Uncle Sam, or John Bull, or do you mean a real person? Or someone like Adam as in as in Adam all die.

Comment: "typical American traits?" you mean stereotypical, right?

Comment: The example sentence could effectively read "Bob is America". That would work and there's no need to bring the word *synedoche* in to confuse matters.

Answer (score 3):

You might refer to that person as an ***[archetype](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archetype)*** of the American people:

> the original pattern or model of which all things of the same type are representations or copies :  prototype
>   *… the House of Commons, the archetype of all the representative assemblies which now meet … — Thomas Babington Macaulay*
>   ; also :  a perfect example
>   *He is the archetype of a successful businessman.*
>   <sub>definition from *[m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archetype)*</sub>

> An *archetype* is a perfect example or model of something. If you have long blonde hair, a sparkly ball gown, and a fairy godmother hovering over your head, you're the *archetype* of a fairytale princess.
>   <sub>from [*vocabulary.com*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/archetype)</sub>

Comment: I agree, archetype is more appropriate. Syndecdoche *is* used where one part of something is referenced to mean the whole thing, but it means it on a more literal level. e.g. calling  a car a "stick-shift", referring to solely the gear mechanism (when they mean the whole car), or saying "America beat Russia", when referring to the American and Russian ice-hockey teams.

Answer (score 1):

In literature [and there is a related usage in religious studies], the word **type** is used for such a representative.

> type noun ​
>
> C1 [ C ] [specialized] [literature]
>
> a person who seems to represent a particular group of people, having
>   all the qualities that you usually connect with that group:
>
> *He doesn't use fully rounded characters in his plays – he uses types.*

[[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/type)]

Answer (score 0):

In movies, actors like Tom Hanks (and the generation preceding, Jimmy Stewart), is called *everyman*. (I have heard this term in literary use, as well.)

This [Salon](http://www.salon.com/2016/09/17/tom-hanks-isnt-everyman-hollywoods-hollow-hero-narrative-prizes-stories-like-sully-above-others/) article discusses how Hanks typifies the American character.

> In this way, Hanks followed the career trajectory of James Stewart, a
>   screwball comedy vet who frequently represented the common good. The
>   Stewart character is both ordinary and exceptional.

*Everyman* refers an ordinary person in extraordinary circumstances.

Other answers have explained why synecdoche doesn't fit. 
Here's a link to synecdoche: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/15567/3306