# Which literary device is "the only place to put the pieces were the bags under my eyes"?

Tags: idioms, metaphors, poetry, literary-device

I am writing a few paragraphs about Rupi Kaur's poetry. I've been trying to think about which literary device is used in this example.

In *milk and honey*, written by Rupi Kaur, she states:

> "the night after you left / i woke up so broken / the only place to put the pieces / were the bags under my eyes"

I've been wondering about this for a bit and I know it would be quite a simple question to answer. I apologize for this. I'm thinking it might be a metaphor or an idiom. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: It's not a set idiom I've heard, only a pun on *bags*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin "Bags under [one's] eyes" is a common phrase in AmE. Putting pieces there is another story.

Comment: I'm American. This is a pun on two meanings of bags. Those under the eyes are not metaphorical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between metonymy and synecdoche?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/what-is-the-difference-between-metonymy-and-synecdoche)

Comment: @YosefBaskin To save this being closed, that's an answer worth giving.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be hyperbole. After being left, the speaker had such terrible sleep that the bags under her eyes were large enough to hold the metaphorical "pieces".